# How to wrap a pointer to pointer for SWIG?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, swig

I see a C library. It uses lots of pointers and pointers to pointers. And in SWIG generates tons of `SWIGTYPE_p_p` used originally for array for functions that take a pointer to array and size. So I want to generate simple C++ stub class like:

```
template<class T>
struct cArray {
    T* data = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;

    viod Clear() {
        delete[] data;
    }

    void Generate(size_t n) {
        if(data != nullptr) {
             Clear();
        }
        size = n;
        data = new T[n];
    }

    T** GetPtr() {
        return &data;
    }

    operator T**() { return GetPtr(); }

    size_t GetSize() {
        return size;
    }

    T* GetElement(int index) {
         return &data[index];
    }
};
```

and I would like SWIG to replace/reinterprite all calls like

`extern AJ_API size_t getchildren(blaType *bla, object** children, size_t numChildren);`

with

`extern AJ_API size_t getchildren(blaType *bla, cArray<object> children, size_t numChildren);`

so it would not get confused and would not generate `SWIGTYPE_p_p...` use less wrappers?

Comment: Given that the size is known by the container why do you want to explicitly pass it in as an argument?

Comment: And why not just work with the native array equivalent in the language you're targeting instead of complicating things?